# zeroinfl model - Warning message: In sqrt(diag(object$vcov)) : NaNs produced

Tags: r

I'm trying to run zero-inflated negative binomial but I'm coming across a "NaNs produced" warning when checking the model that prevents me from seeing outcomes. Here's some mock data that's a simplified version of my actual data - my real data has many more observations per species + more species:

```
df1 <- data.frame(species = c("Rufl","Rufl","Rufl","Rufl","Assp","Assp","Assp","Assp","Elre", "Elre","Elre", "Elre","Soca","Soca","Soca","Soca"),
                  state = c("warmed","ambient","warmed","ambient","warmed","ambient","warmed","ambient","warmed","ambient","warmed","ambient","warmed","ambient","warmed","ambient"),
                  p_eaten = c(0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 15, 0, 20, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 87, 0))
```

Here's the model I'm attempting to run, with an interaction between state and species:

```
library(pscl)
mod1 <- zeroinfl(p_eaten ~ state * species,
                     dist = 'negbin',
                     data = df1)
summary(mod1)
```

This is when I get `Warning message: In sqrt(diag(object$vcov)) : NaNs produced`. How can I fix this warning message so that I'm able to see model outcomes? Thanks!

Using R version 4.0.2, Mac OS X 10.13.6

Comment: Could you show us the results of `with(df1,table(species,state,p_eaten==0))` for your full data set? Or at least see if there are categories with zero values equal to 0?

Comment: Yes, checking this on my full data it does appear that there are categories equal to zero. I'll likely go with your first suggestion of "ignoring the problem" and also run some likelihood ratio tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a case of [complete separation](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logisticprobit-regression-and-how-do-we-deal-with-them/), although it's impossible to know for sure without your full data set.

This is likely to happen when you have categories that are all-zero, or all-nonzero. In the example you gave above:

```r
with(df1,table(species,state,p_eaten==0))
```

shows that are no observations where species=="Rufl", state=="ambient", and `p`==0 is `FALSE`; in other words, *all of the observations are zero  for this combination of factors*. Thus any coefficient that involves a comparison with this state will have a parameter value of large magnitude (i.e. abs(beta) >> 1); it should theoretically be *infinite*, but is usually somewhere between 10 and 30 (depending on where the numerical methods give up). These coefficients will either have ridiculously large standard errors and (Wald) confidence intervals, or (as in your case) `NaN` values.

This description holds for the zero-inflation coefficients for `speciesRufl` and `statewarmed:speciesRufl`. The count-model coefficients are not large, but still have `NaN` standard errors, I think because their uncertainties are related to the uncertainty of the zero-inflation coefficients.

```r
Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)             -0.69312    1.00016  -0.693 0.488307    
...
speciesRufl             -1.69427        NaN     NaN      NaN    

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
...
speciesRufl               17.560        NaN     NaN      NaN
```

What can you do about this?

- Ignore the problem. You won't be able to get reliable standard errors (and hence p-values, confidence intervals, etc.) for the coefficients that are affected by the problem, but the model is still OK in principle. Doing *likelihood ratio tests* (comparing the log-likelihood of models with vs. without specified sets of predictors) is still OK and can be used to get p-values for specified effects, e.g. via `lmtest::lrtest()`
- Simplify your model: lump some categories, decide whether you really need zero-inflation, etc.
- There are a variety of other approaches that involve *penalization* or imposing Bayesian priors on the relevant coefficients to keep them sensible (e.g. the `brglm2` package), but I don't know if any of these are implemented/available for `zeroinfl` models [you could do this, e.g., via the `brms` package, but that would involve a lot of work getting up to speed with the foundations of the package]

Comment: I don't usually have the temerity to edit your posts but I think that here I'm on safe ground.

Comment: It's more or less equivalent, because I was saying "there are no zeros in the data set for this combination of factors" and you are saying "the entry in the table is zero"

Comment: Now I'm confused. How are those equivalent? What would it mean to "have a zero" for this combination of factors?

Comment: I mean that I'm tabulating (species × state × (p_eaten==0)), i.e. for each combination of species and state, how many observations of the response variable `p_eaten` are equal to zero? For species==Rufl, state==warmed, the count of p==0 is zero - or in other words, *none of the observed responses for this combination of factors is equal to zero*

Comment: The count of p_eaten==0 for that combination of 2 factors is 1.

Comment: OK. I see what you're saying now. After you read this I'll delete all my comments. (The count of Rufl+ambient with p_eaten==0 was actually 2)

Comment: Is my statement in the answer actually correct and understandable now? I hope so ...

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty thin data for such a complex model but if you do an `xtabs` on your version of the dataframe you see that one of your reference categories has zero counts. If you swap the levels of your `state` variable , the NA's go away although some of the large standard errors remain.

```
xtabs(p_eaten~ state + species, data=df1)
         species
state     Assp Elre Rufl Soca
  ambient    1    2    0    3
  warmed    15   20    3   87
```

Uncleaned up console output follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(species = c("Rufl","Rufl","Rufl","Rufl","Assp","Assp","Assp","Assp","Elre", "Elre","Elre", "Elre","Soca","Soca","Soca","Soca"),
+                   state = factor(c("warmed","ambient","warmed","ambient","warmed","ambient","warmed","ambient","warmed","ambient","warmed","ambient","warmed","ambient","warmed","ambient"), levels=c("warmed","ambient")),
+                   p_eaten = c(0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 15, 0, 20, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 87, 0))
> xtabs(p_eaten~ state + species, data=df1)
         species
state     Assp Elre Rufl Soca
  warmed    15   20    3   87
  ambient    1    2    0    3
```

Attempt:

```
> library(pscl)
> mod1 <- zeroinfl(p_eaten ~ state * species,
+                      dist = 'negbin',
+                      data = df1)
> summary(mod1)

Call:
zeroinfl(formula = p_eaten ~ state * species, data = df1, dist = "negbin")

Pearson residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.98868 -0.80384 -0.00342  0.80387  0.98872 

Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)               2.708e+00  2.582e-01  10.488  < 2e-16 ***
stateambient             -3.401e+00  1.033e+00  -3.292 0.000994 ***
speciesElre               2.877e-01  3.416e-01   0.842 0.399623    
speciesRufl              -1.671e+00  6.874e-01  -2.431 0.015068 *  
speciesSoca               1.758e+00  2.796e-01   6.288 3.22e-10 ***
stateambient:speciesElre  8.714e-01  1.400e+00   0.622 0.533627    
stateambient:speciesRufl -3.972e-04         NA      NA       NA    
stateambient:speciesSoca -2.763e-02  1.218e+00  -0.023 0.981906    
Log(theta)                1.501e+01  1.848e+02   0.081 0.935234    

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)              -1.327e-04  1.414e+00   0.000    1.000
stateambient             -8.538e+00  1.206e+02  -0.071    0.944
speciesElre               1.379e-04  2.000e+00   0.000    1.000
speciesRufl              -1.267e-01  2.083e+00  -0.061    0.952
speciesSoca               1.757e-04  2.000e+00   0.000    1.000
stateambient:speciesElre  8.016e+00  1.206e+02   0.066    0.947
stateambient:speciesRufl  1.757e+01         NA      NA       NA
stateambient:speciesSoca  8.411e+00  1.206e+02   0.070    0.944
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Theta = 3316847.5216 
Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 41 
Log-likelihood: -21.87 on 17 Df
Warning message:
In sqrt(diag(object$vcov)) : NaNs produced
```

Variance-covariance matrices are supposed to be positive definite and negative values may preclude inversion efforts. When a similat question was posed on CrossValidated.com, Ben Bolker suggested using brglm2 version of glm:

```
> library(brglm2)
> summary(m1 <- glm(p_eaten~ state * species, data=df1,
+             family=poisson,
+             method="brglmFit"))

Call:
glm(formula = p_eaten ~ state * species, family = poisson, data = df1, 
    method = "brglmFit")

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-9.3541  -1.8708  -0.7071   0.8567   5.7542  

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                2.0477     0.2540   8.062 7.52e-16 ***
stateambient              -2.3354     0.8551  -2.731  0.00631 ** 
speciesElre                0.2796     0.3366   0.831  0.40619    
speciesRufl               -1.4881     0.5918  -2.514  0.01192 *  
speciesSoca                1.7308     0.2756   6.281 3.37e-10 ***
stateambient:speciesElre   0.2312     1.0863   0.213  0.83142    
stateambient:speciesRufl   0.3895     1.7369   0.224  0.82258    
stateambient:speciesSoca  -0.8835     1.0141  -0.871  0.38362    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 443.21  on 15  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 183.08  on  8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 225.38

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1
```

In point of fact the need for an interaction seems questionable. The change in deviance with removal of the interaction terms is miniscule. Hard to know whether than mich also occur with your full dataset.

Comment: I don't think `brglm2` handles zero-inflation though ... ?

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that this was a zero-inflation adjusted model.